# Execute Oracle stored procedure from .net application

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a stored procedure from my .net application, but I get an error

> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"

Any recommdendations?

```
 await Context.Database.SqlQuery<Equipment>(_execPackage, new OracleParameter("ID", obID),
                new OracleParameter("Time", time),
                new OracleParameter("rNo", No).ToListAsync();

 private readonly string _execPackage = $@" EXEC procedurename(:ID,:Time,:rNo)";
```

Comment: Have you tried the answer upvoted in this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273638/executing-an-oracle-stored-procedure-within-entityframework

Comment: You may also try `CALL` instead of `EXEC`.

Comment: This worked ---    await Context.Database.SqlQuery<object>($@" CALL procedurename(:p1,:p2,:p3)",
    new OracleParameter("p1", obID),
     new OracleParameter("p2", time),
     new OracleParameter("p3", No).ToListAsync();

Answer (score 0):

This is worked

```
 await Context.Database.SqlQuery<object>($@" CALL procedurename(:p1,:p2,:p3)",
    new OracleParameter("p1", obID),
     new OracleParameter("p2", time),
     new OracleParameter("p3", Nmbr).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might seem verbose, but this is how I prefer setting up calls to stored procedures:

```
using (var context = new DbContext()) // you don't have to strictly use this to reference the context, it's just what i gravitate towards
{
    var in_Id = new OracleParameter("in_ID", OracleDbType.TYPE, obID, ParameterDirection.Input);
    var in_time = new OracleParameter("in_time", OracleDbType.TYPE, time, ParameterDirection.Input);
    var in_rNo = new OracleParameter("in_rNo", OracleDbType.TYPE, No, ParameterDirection.Input);

   await  context.Database.SqlQuery<object>("BEGIN procedurename(:in_Id, :in_time, :in_rNo); END;", in_Id, in_time, in_rNo).ToListAsync();

}
```

One thing to note, if the ID parameter is a PK with a sequence that autogenerates its value, you'll want to reference the sequence instead of passing in a parameter:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<object>("BEGIN procedurename(SEQUENCE_NAME.nextval, :in_time, :in_rNo); END;", in_Id, in_time, in_rNo);
```